# Fastest way to upload big files

Tags: javascript, php, fine-uploader

I've implemented fineuploader to upload a file without reloading the page.  Problem is it is very slow and potentially fails for vary large files (~300M).  Note that I am only using Fineuploader 3.1, but expect it will not make a difference to use a more current version.

My question is whether I shouldn't use some sort of Ajax based file upload approach at all for large files, but based on their size fall back to some more traditional solution which reloads the page?  What would be the fastest way to upload a big file using a website and not FTP, etc?

Comment: Whether you use javascript / ajax or a traditional upload, they are all normal http post requests so the speed will be the same. The only difference is the user experience.

Comment: Either if you use HTTP or FTP, they are on top of the TCP, where the transfer rate if established by the network infrastructure, usually by measuring the packet loss. The only thing you can do is to check that the transfer rate is not explicitly limited somewhere on your side, otherwise you can't do anything.

Comment: You said it yourself. Consider using FTP for large files. It's the protocol made specifically to send/recieve files. HTTP is designed to send/recieve text...Either way neither FTP not HTTP will be effective if the bottleneck is your internet upload speed.

Comment: @Anupam  Will FTP be approximately the same speed as HTTP?  Off topic, could a decent user experience be implemented using FTP?

Comment: If you're at the point of "how should I upload large files?" - the question is too broad for SO. As you can see below, unfortunately, you've attracted lib-recommendations for the smaller-in-scope "how to upload files in a resumable way with js" pseudo-question that you've asked.

Comment: @user1032531 It depends. This link provides a good comparision and explains when would one perform better than the other.  http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/ftp-vs-http.html . The WebUI can be made as good as you can make your PHP page to be.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at:
[Resumable.js](http://resumablejs.com/) Fault Tolerant Resumable File Uploads in JavaScript

As far as I think large files are prone to fault so it is a good idea to make it ressumable.

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader has changed a lot since 3.1.  The current version is already 4.4.  You likely will notice a big difference if you upgrade.  Also, Fine Uploader is not causing you failures, your network connection is the culprit.

Fine Uploader 5.0 is set to be released next week, and it includes one big feature that will help you specifically as this feature is aimed as speeding up single file large uploads: concurrent chunking.  No other upload library offers this feature (it was very complicated to implement).  The concurrent chunking feature has been shown to speed up single file large uploads by a factor of at least 2.  It does this by sending as many chunks as possible at the same time for a single file.  You can read more about this feature in the pre release notes at http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/develop/features/concurrent-chunking.html.

Note that Fine Uploader also offers the same features as resumable.js along with many other features such as auto retry, image scaling, form support, direct uploads to S3 and Azure, and more.