# uploading video file not working

Tags: php

I want to upload video files in php for that i am using following code

**PHP**

```
$newUploadDir = "c://video";
$idx = "file";
if (isset($_FILES[$idx]) && is_array($_FILES[$idx])) {
       echo "file set";
    foreach ($_FILES[$idx]["error"] as $key => $error) {
       echo "loop";
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

            echo "<br/>dd2";
            $tmp_name = $_FILES[$idx]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES[$idx]["name"][$key];
            $ext1 = explode(".", $name);
            $extension = end($ext1);

            $newfilename = "test".".".$extension;
            $video_types = array('mp4', 'avi','webm');
            if (in_array($extension, $video_types)) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newUploadDir.$newfilename)) {
                    echo "uploaded to folder";

                } else {
                    echo "Not uploaded to folder";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "not uploaded $error";
        }
    }
}

echo "ok";
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://localhost/fileupload/video.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input id="file1" name="file[]" type="file"/>
    <input name="userId" type="text"  value="2"/>
    <input id="Submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**Output**

> file setloopnot uploaded 1ok

Video file is not uploading. How to resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501749/php-move-uploaded-file-error

Comment: try to error this in your else statement **echo "Not uploaded because of error #".$_FILES["file"]["error"];**

Comment: the error code is 1(UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE): Your file exceeded the upload_max_filesize. If you are permitted to change this, just change this.

Comment: well change that file_upload_size limit in your php.ini file

Comment: search for upload_max_filesize in php.ini file and change its value

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave it is showing `Not uploaded because of error #Arrayok`   Not shing error

Comment: have you gone through with this http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php ?

Comment: Yes it was due to large file size

Comment: also try to update your php.ini file's **post_max_size** , **upload_max_filesize** and you also update your **apache.conf** file  **KeepAliveTimeout** .. try all these

Comment: great .. u know what .. at times anwering questions,giving code and getting upvotes is not all about .. at times just giving a way or hint is all about .. a hint to track issues .. that's when you imrove.. isnt it ? :)

Comment: @xrcwrn btw, glad to see java guy learning php and improving him/herself :) ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126799/discussion-between-xrcwrn-and-mittul-at-technobrave).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you try to upload very large (video) files, probably the upload file size limit will not let you do that. Instead of regular file upload, there are other possibities. For the begining, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973358/fastest-way-to-upload-big-files), [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/) or [this](http://resumablejs.com/).

An other aproach would be to use third party services like Amazon S3, Microsoft Azure, etc.